# Modifying a query that had a left join and an inner join

Tags: mysql

The query below sums up `points` from the MySQL table "comment" when the following conditions are met:

1. The `loginid` when `l.username = '$profile'` is found.
2. All the `submissionid`s are found that have the `loginid` from #1 above.
3. All the `commentid`s with the `submissionid`s from #2 above are found, and the corresponding `points` are summed.

Now, how could I make a different query that returns an array of all of the `comment`s in #3 above rather than summing the `point`s?

Here are the MySQL tables involved:

login:

`logind username created activated`

submission:

`submissionid loginid`

comment:

`commentid submissionid points comment`

Query:

```
SELECT 
    l.loginid, 
    l.username, 
    l.created,
    l.activated,
    COALESCE(scs.total, 0) AS commentsreceivedvalue

FROM login l    


LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT S2.loginid, SUM(C2.points) AS total 
FROM submission S2
INNER JOIN comment C2
ON S2.submissionid = C2.submissionid
GROUP BY S2.loginid
) scs ON scs.loginid = l.loginid


WHERE l.activated = 1
AND l.username = '$profile'


GROUP BY l.loginid
ORDER BY commentsreceivedvalue DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it as simple as:

```
SELECT l.loginid, l.username, l.created, l.activated, scs.commentid, scs.comment
  FROM login AS l
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT S2.loginid, c2.commentid, c2.comment 
               FROM submission AS S2
               JOIN comment    AS C2 ON S2.submissionid = C2.submissionid
            ) AS scs ON scs.loginid = l.loginid
 WHERE l.activated = 1
   AND l.username = '$profile'
 ORDER BY scs.commentid DESC;
```

The outer GROUP BY in the original was not doing anything useful.  The ORDER BY in the original was replaced here by the ordering in reverse order of comment ID, which is an approximation to reverse chronological order (most recent first, in other words).